# Woocommerce custom function - Add to cart

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

We had been using a custom function in our theme.

```
    add_shortcode('add_to_cart_button', 'add_to_cart_func');

    function add_to_cart_func($atts) {

      $str = '<span class="new_product_header"><span class="button single_add_to_cart_button" onclick="jQuery(\'.single_add_to_cart_button \').click()">ADD TO CART</span></span>';

      return $str;

    }
```

Worked fine until last WP update, now when you click the button, it does an infinite loop of adding the product to the cart over and over.

Any ideas on why the infinite loop  or a way to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique thing in your code on line

```
$str = '<span class="new_product_header"><span class="button single_add_to_cart_button" onclick="jQuery(\'.single_add_to_cart_button \').click()">ADD TO CART</span></span>';
```

You have attached click event to span having class .single_add_to_cart_button and on click event your trying to run following code same element.

```
jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').click();
```

So basically when your event fire it keep firing event.

Just remove

```
onclick="jQuery(\'.single_add_to_cart_button \').click()"
```

And all will be fine.

Comment: Thank you, your comment pointed me in the right direction.
we added a single_add_to_cart2 class for display as to not loop and it's working!

Comment: That's gr8, Can you please check my answer :)